# Getting undefined while defining value for keys of an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var playlistResponse = {
  "id": "59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC",
  "followers": {
    "href": null,
    "total": 143350
  },
  "trackInfo": {
    "playlistType": "favorites",
    "lastUpdated": "2015-11-26T19:13:31",
    "tracks": [
      {
        "id": "0C0XlULifJtAgn6ZNCW2eu",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "Travis Scott",
        "title": "goosebumps",
        "length": "4:03",
        "playCount": 404489462,
        "genre": "rap"
      },
      {
        "id": "4OHNH3sDzIxnmUADXzv2kT",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "LCD Soundsystem",
        "title": "Someone Great",
        "length": "6:30",
        "playCount": 23765430,
        "genre": "alternative"
      },
      {
        "id": "3twNvmDtFQtAd5gMKedhLD",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "Cut Copy",
        "title": "Hearts On Fire",
        "length": "4:52",
        "playCount": 23098109,
        "genre": "alternative"
      },
      {
        "id": "5m4VYOPoIpkV0XgOiRKkWC",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "Cut Copy",
        "title": "HUMBLE.",
        "length": "4:11",
        "playCount": 768356720,
        "genre": "rap"
      },
      {
        "id": "1l63szZeUpN1m87MOD1u7K",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "Whitney Houston",
        "title": "I Wanna Dance With Somebody (Who Loves Me)",
        "length": "4:51",
        "playCount": 184656875,
        "genre": "pop"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This is the object I am trying to extract information from. I am trying to get an object with the list of `title` and `length`. This is my current code and output

```
function findAllLonger(playListInput, trackTime) {
  var listOfTracks = {};
  var arrayOfTracks = playListInput.trackInfo.tracks;

  arrayOfTracks.forEach(function (value) {
    listOfTracks[value.title] = listOfTracks[value.length];
  })

  return listOfTracks;
}

/* Output
{ goosebumps: undefined,
  'Someone Great': undefined,
  'Hearts On Fire': undefined,
  'HUMBLE.': undefined,
  'I Wanna Dance With Somebody (Who Loves Me)': undefined }
*/
```

I don't understand why I can't seem to access my length property. It returns `undefined` yet if I were to run `console.log(listOfTracks[0].length)` I get a defined value but this code should be equivalent to the one I have in my `forEach` loop. What am I missing here?

Comment: should be `listOfTracks[value.title] = value.length;`

Comment: Ugh. Thanks @Pointy. Can't believe I missed something so simple. Any idea why my first `title` value of `goosebumps` is not written as a string?

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis it *is* a string. All object keys are strings (unless they are Symbols, which isn't the case here). I guess your console chooses to show the values without quotes unless they contain symbols like space or a dot. I'd also guess that a dash, plus, etc. are going to trigger this behaviour - anything that cannot be used to fetch the property using dot notation.

Comment: @VLAZ I figured it had to be a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```js
var playlistResponse = {
  "id": "59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC",
  "followers": {
    "href": null,
    "total": 143350
  },
  "trackInfo": {
    "playlistType": "favorites",
    "lastUpdated": "2015-11-26T19:13:31",
    "tracks": [
      {
        "id": "0C0XlULifJtAgn6ZNCW2eu",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "Travis Scott",
        "title": "goosebumps",
        "length": "4:03",
        "playCount": 404489462,
        "genre": "rap"
      },
      {
        "id": "4OHNH3sDzIxnmUADXzv2kT",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "LCD Soundsystem",
        "title": "Someone Great",
        "length": "6:30",
        "playCount": 23765430,
        "genre": "alternative"
      },
      {
        "id": "3twNvmDtFQtAd5gMKedhLD",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "Cut Copy",
        "title": "Hearts On Fire",
        "length": "4:52",
        "playCount": 23098109,
        "genre": "alternative"
      },
      {
        "id": "5m4VYOPoIpkV0XgOiRKkWC",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "Cut Copy",
        "title": "HUMBLE.",
        "length": "4:11",
        "playCount": 768356720,
        "genre": "rap"
      },
      {
        "id": "1l63szZeUpN1m87MOD1u7K",
        "type": "track",
        "artist": "Whitney Houston",
        "title": "I Wanna Dance With Somebody (Who Loves Me)",
        "length": "4:51",
        "playCount": 184656875,
        "genre": "pop"
      }
    ]
  }
};

function findAllLonger(playListInput, trackTime) {
  var listOfTracks = {};
  var arrayOfTracks = playListInput.trackInfo.tracks;

  arrayOfTracks.forEach(function (value) {
    listOfTracks[value.title] = value.length;
  })

  return listOfTracks;
}

console.log(findAllLonger(playlistResponse))

/* Output
{ goosebumps: '4:03',
  'Someone Great': '6:30',
  'Hearts On Fire': '4:52',
  'HUMBLE.': '4:11',
  'I Wanna Dance With Somebody (Who Loves Me)': '4:51' }
*/
```

You were trying to access the attribute "6:30" (e.g.) on the listOfTracks.